# Display SQL Table in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to display a table in php. I have established a valid connection. I get the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project.php on line 17
```

The page's code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Site Michael Mazur</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
        //connect to DB
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","mike","mike");
 $db_found = mysql_select_db("my_guitar_shop2");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT firstName,lastName FROM customers");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should post a little more or the whole file if it's not too big.

Comment: Your code seems to be truncated...

Comment: It keeps truncating my code...I am trying to edit as we speak...I dont have enough points to upload the file.

Comment: You can put the code on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: To be honest, I do not see anything wrong with your code. What happens if you put that `echo` statement all on one line (that shouldn't be the issue though)?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?  Everything looks fine so either you are using an older version of php that doesn't support some things or you haven't pasted your entire actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rest of your while loop could look like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    print "<tr><td>".$row['Firstname']."</td><td>".$row['Lastname']."</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```

Try putting these lines on a single line as i have done above.

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";
```

like

```
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th></tr>";
```

Other useful options here.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: For some reason didnt like the multi line echo first name lastname?! I put it all on one line as you suggested and it fixed the problem.

Comment: @YoungGuy, PHP weirdness - glad you got it working.  I don't multi-line echo too much - try to keep it lean and mean.

Comment: In order to make it work for multiple line you need to do it as I have suggested.

Comment: Very weird, though, it must be a PHP configuration problem, as `echo` does support multiline input. Paste your code here (the echo part) http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and you'll see that it outputs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Given that part of the page's code is missing, this is only a guess. But it looks like part of your problem is that you've double-selected the database (a no-no).

Also, the `while` statement looks slightly suspect (no opening brace to verify context).

Additionally, if you are going to pass `$con` to the database selector, you should also pass it to the `mysql_query` calls (good practice for readability).

Comment: I still dont understand what the problem is with line 17? the </tr>;